# Indexing a critical edition (edtext and ibibleverse) according to \pstart and line

Tags: indexing, reledmac, reledpar, bibleref

Currently working on a critical edition with parallel translation, using `reledmac`, `reledpar` and `bibleref-french`.

For the indexing of this text, I use `indextools` to get two indices: one for the original text (latin in the example below) and one for the biblical references.

So far, I managed to get indices where each entry refers to the page and the line. Since lineation restarts at each `\pstart`, I would like the entry to refer to the pstart instead of the page. How could I achieve that?

Here's a MWE (not so minimal with reledmac options, but I did not want to risk messing up a functionning setup)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\usepackage[indextestamentsL]{bibleref-french}
\biblerefstyle{defaultshorter}
\usepackage[xindy]{indextools}


\usepackage[noeledsec,noend,noledgroup,xindy,xindy+hyperref, series={A, B, C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage[sameparallelpagenumber, advancedshiftedpstarts]{reledpar}
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\firstlinenumR{10000000}
\lineation{pstart}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{{\textit{\alph{footnoteA}}}}
\newcommand{\witness}{\textbf}

\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
\Xlemmadisablefontselection[A]
\Xnotenumfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\Xnotefontsize{\scriptsize}
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{:~}
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$~}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline
\Xlinenumannotationonlyfirstintwo
\Xpstarteverytime[A]

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote@typeset}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA@typeset}
\MakePerPage{footnoteB@typeset}

\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}

\makeindex[title=Scripture,name=scr]
\makeindex
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[scr]}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\pstart
Lorem ipsum\edindex{ipse}...
\pend

\pstart
O \edtext{quam}{\lemma{quam}\Afootnote{quem \witness{H}}} tristis\edindex{tristis, e}...
\pend

\pstart
In principio creavit Deus cœlum et terram.\footnoteA{\ibibleverse{Gn}(1:1)}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue

\pstart
Translation 1
\pend

\pstart
Translation 2
\pend

\pstart
Translation 3
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\newpage
\printindex[scr]
\printindex
\end{document}
```